# What does "only if" mean exactly?

Tags: logic, notation, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

I learned the followings; 'if', 'only if', and 'if and only if'.

I understood like the followings;

'$A$ if $B$' means that 'That $B$ holds implies that $A$ holds'

'$A$ only if $B$' means that 'That $A$ holds implies that $B$ holds'

'$A$ if and only if $B$' means that 'That $B$ holds implies that $A$ holds. At the same 
time, that $A$ holds implies that $B$ holds'

---

However, in the textbook states 'DP can be applied numerically only if the dimensions of the spaces are relatively small.'

I do not understand why the author uses only if instead of if.

Is there any exception of these notations with respect to 'if' that I do not know?

Comment: It's saying that DP CAN'T be applied if the dimensions AREN'T relatively small.

Comment: @ZacharySelk I understood from the back-and-forth context. I was just wondering about that notation. However, thanks to you, I can get assured about the meaning. Thank you^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"A if B".      When B is true then A must be true (sufficient).

"A only if B". When B is false then A must be false (necessary).

"A if and only if B". When B is true A must be true, When B is false A must be false. (necessary and sufficient)

"if" allows A to be any truth value when B is false.
"only if" allows A to be any truth value when B is true.

Comment: Ah!!!! the second one means "FALSE!!!". wow... tidy answer!!

Comment: A clear answer (+1). :-)